# Postfix can send, but not receive external email with configuration in CentOS 8

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot, centos8

I have two problems, and I believe they are somewhat related. First, I can receive email from domains in my local server in Roundcube and Horde, but not in Thunderbird or Mac Mail. Secondly, I can't receive external email anywhere, and this is the main problem that concerns me. When I send a message, I get a flash on the screen saying the message is being sent, and I get NO error message. But, the email is not received by the recipient.
This is the code I added at the end of the original /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myhostname = mail.charlotsa.com
mydomain = charlotsa.com
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 24.197.10.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reje$
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.charlotsa.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.charlotsa.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

I made only two other changes to the original "/etc/postfix/main.cf" file. First, I commented out the ssl paths, because I already had a certificate for my email server, which I added at the bottom of the file. Second, I added this code to the alias section of the file:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
```

But I haven't tried another domain yet because I want to get this resolved first.
When I test port 25 with the command, "netstat -plnt |grep :25", this is the result:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 24.197.10.18:25         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Here's my configuration in Thunderbird:
[Thunderbird email configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q7s1.jpg)

Finally, I have set up my DNS name server in "/var/named" and it is pointing to my ip.
I believe the issues with Thunderbird and Mac Mail will no longer be a problem, once I am able to receive external emails. If someone can help me, I will be very grateful. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I did was comment out the line

```
mynetworks = 24.197.10.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
```

and change `inet_interfaces` to `all`.